# dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN3tbb4task13note_affinityEt when installing ncl

Tags: dyld, ncl

Good day,
I am trying to install NCL on my MacProbook from so many days but i am getting this linking error:
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN3tbb4task13note_affinityEt
Referenced from: /Users/kanwai/opt/anaconda3/envs/ncl_to_python/lib/libtiledb.dylib
Expected in: /Users/kanwai/opt/anaconda3/envs/ncl_to_python/lib/libtbb.dylib
in /Users/kanwai/opt/anaconda3/envs/ncl_to_python/lib/libtiledb.dylib
Abort trap: 6
Any idea how to fix it?